The app will crash on IOS 18 when send a network request
The code like this:
NSURLSessionConfiguration *configuration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
configuration.URLCache = [[NSURLCache alloc] initWithMemoryCapacity:20 * 1024 * 1024
                                                     diskCapacity:100 * 1024 * 1024
                                                        diskPath:@"myCache"];
if (!configuration) {
    NSLog(@"Failed to create session configuration.");
    return;
}


NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:configuration];
if (!session) {
    NSLog(@"Failed to create session.");
    return;
}


NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://example.com"];
if (!url) {
    NSLog(@"Invalid URL.");
    return;
}

NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
if (!request) {
    NSLog(@"Failed to create request.");
    return;
}

NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask = [session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error.localizedDescription);
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Data received: %@", data);
    }
}];

if (!dataTask) {
    NSLog(@"Failed to create data task.");
   return;
}

dataTask.priority = NSURLSessionTaskPriorityDefault;  


[dataTask resume];

the error message:

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSFileManager createDirectoryAtURL:withIntermediateDirectories:attributes:error:]: URL is nil'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x1848bd08c 0x181bbf2e4 0x183585f48 0x185d2f2bc 0x185d2ec7c 0x10709271c 0x1070a3f04 0x185d2ea88 0x185d2db20 0x185d2d5f4 0x185d2d07c 0x185d274b0 0x185dd82c4 0x185dd8214 0x185dd730c 0x107090a30 0x10709271c 0x10709a5e8 0x10709b394 0x10709cb20 0x1070a85f0 0x1070a7c00 0x20bc27c7c 0x20bc24488)
libc++abi: terminating due to uncaught exception of type NSException

the network request could be worked well under ios 18

initWithMemoryCapacity:diskCapacity:diskPath: was deprecated iOS 13.
You should use the replacement initialiser
configuration.URLCache = [[NSURLCache alloc] initWithMemoryCapacity:20*1024*1024 
diskCapacity:100*1024*1024 
directoryUrl: nil];


Thanks for your suggestion, but it still doesn't work .
